# Azure AD: how to grant permission for all users within my AD tenet

Tags: azure-active-directory

I am **not** an admin of my azure active directory. Currently my web api application will able to read directory data when I or any user manually going to azure portal and click `Grant Permissions'.

I set `Read directory data` under `DELEGATED PERMISSIONS`.

[image]

But, I can't go to to each user and ask for same. Is there any way to do this at once for all users of my AD tenet? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are not an admin, no you cannot grant permissions on behalf of any other users. The most you can do is grant the application permissions equal to what your user can do, which is what the "Access the directory as the signed-in user" permission does.

However, depending on the data you are trying to read, you may be able to access that data without needing other users to consent. For example, any user has the ability to grant the application the ability to read basic information about all other users in the tenant. You will need to elaborate on your scenario.

Comment: so, if admin will do grant permission, it will applicable to all user, right?

Comment: Yeah, if an admin clicks that, the consent will run for all users.

Comment: But you can read group memberships without needing an admin AFAIK.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification.

Comment: @juunas, how can I read group memberships without needing an admin?

Comment: Well, the funny thing is, you can actually get a group's members with User.ReadBasic.All: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/group_list_members, but you need admin consent to get a user's memberships: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_list_memberof. One option to get group memberships is to set `"groupMembershipClaims": "SecurityGroup"` in your app's manifest, then you get them in the Id token. That is limited to 200 groups IIRC, in which case you would have to call the API.

Comment: @juunas, thanks for the reply. When I set `"groupMembershipClaims": "SecurityGroup"` in app's manifest file, looks like there is restriction only up to 5 groups, if user has more then 5 groups then I'm getting   `hasgroups: "true",`

Comment: Okay. The limit is much lower than what I remember. You might need administrator consent to get the permission you need to get group memberships via MS Graph.